# Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I installed rails on my computer, made under this instruction -https://coderwall.com/p/auvm9g 
When installing a new project - rails new my_project -d mysql

```
    Installing mysql2 (0.3.13) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/albert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@kyrgyz-tours/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/albert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@kyrgyz-tours/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thank you all! Gem mysql2 installed :)

Comment: did you install mysql-server,mysql-client,libmysql-dev, libmysql-ruby ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems like that you do not have mysql installed in your system please install `mysql-server`, `mysql-client` and the necessary libraries eg: libmysql-dev...........

```
 -----
 mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
 -----
```

you can follow http://ariejan.net/2007/12/12/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntudebian/

if Mac os
http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html

also

Using a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or MacPorts makes it fairly straight-forward to fix this. The binary distribution of MySQL direct from Oracle and the one bundled with OS X itself does not have the development headers, of which mysql.h is one of them.

and

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: My system Mac Os, mysql server installed, these commands will not work

Comment: ooh ok ...sorry i thought it is linux..

Comment: Please see my post link it is best for your answer

Comment: I run - brew install mysql, but nothing happened, show - Warning: mysql-5.6.13 already installed

Comment: Setting env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" before running gem.

Comment: please let me know what it is given  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config